# error LNK2019 - I feel like my code should compile but am getting this error

Tags: c++, lnk2019

If someone could help me figure out why this error is happening I would be very very happy. I feel like my code should compile yet I am getting this error with both of my void functions.

Here is my code...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>


using namespace std;

// global constant variables
const int YEARS = 8;
const int MONTHS = 12;
const int SPACER =5;

// function prototypes

// function to read in values
void getData(double[][MONTHS], int[]);
// function to display values in table format
void printData(double[][MONTHS], int[]);


// function to print data to screen in table format using arrays

int main()
{
    double rain [YEARS][MONTHS];
    int years[YEARS];

    getData(rain, years);
    printData(rain, years);

return 0;
}


// function definitions 

void getData (double rainArray[][YEARS], int yearArray[])
{
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("rainfall.txt");

    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file, shutting down now.\n" ;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++)
        {
            fin >> yearArray[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < MONTHS; j++)
            {
                fin >> rainArray[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    fin.close();
}   

void printData (double rainArray[][YEARS], int yearArray[])
{

    for ( int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++){
        cout << yearArray[i] << setw(SPACER);
        for ( int j = 0; j < MONTHS; j ++)
            cout << rainArray[i][j] << setw(SPACER);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Could you please include the *actual* error message and perhaps the lines that caused those error(s) (if applicable).

Comment: Did you look up what that error meant?

Comment: Where are those functions implemented?

Comment: @PeterL., just scroll down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dimension mismatch in your `genData` parameter and `rain` array:
You have:

```
  double rain [YEARS][MONTHS];
```

but used it in a wrong way:

```
 void getData (double rainArray[][YEARS], int yearArray[])
                    //^^^ should be rainArray[YEARS][MONTHS]
```

similar issue for the `printData` function